# What is the significance of James Cole's tattoos?

Tags: character, 12-monkeys

In [12 Monkeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_Monkeys), James Cole has some tattoos, one on the back of his neck looks like a bar-code and another on the side of his neck near to the ear  looks like some digits.

[image]

Is there any significance to those tattoos? They are shown various times in the film.

Comment: I think the bar code is just part of his prisoner identity (and maybe the digits also?).

Comment: @ChristianRau also though the same but there is no mention of it in the film. May be someone can elaborate it.

Comment: Need screenshot. :/

Comment: @Mistu4u added, but its not too clear.

Comment: They scanned his neck tattoo when he met with the scientists before going up to the surface.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Introduction to Twelve Monkeys [from the Programme Notes](http://www.smart.co.uk/dreams/monkfact.htm):

> And, his stark look was further enhanced by his makeup artist, Cristina Bartolucci, who, everyday, etched a trio of tattoos onto Willis' scalp and neck - **one that indicated his prisoner number, and a pair of bar-codes, the kind imprinted on packaged goods, on each side of his neck.**

This is also repeated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_Monkeys#Casting):

> The actor had a trio of tattoos drawn onto his scalp and neck each day when filming: one that indicated his prisoner number, and a pair of barcodes on each side of his neck.

I don't think that there's any particular significance to the tattoos other than to emphasise the dystopian undercurrent in the story and remind us every now and then that Cole is actually a prisoner (from the future).